'TwoCaptcha' object has no attribute 'normal'
I'm working on a project where I want to integrate a captcha-bypassing feature. I've been using the 2captcha service for this and it was quite successful until I switched from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu 22.04).
I keep receiving the same error - 'TwoCaptcha' object has no attribute 'normal' when I try to run this function:
def solve_captcha(image_path):
    solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)
    try:
        result = solver.normal(image_path)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
    else:
        return result['code']

The problem is, that I have the same library version installed on both systems. I didn't change anything in the function code above after transitioning, and official documentation includes said attribute in its examples.
Can anyone help me understand the issue?
I've tried to search both: library documentation (https://pypi.org/project/2captcha-python/), as well as examples on the official service's webpage (https://2captcha.com/api-docs/normal-captcha), but they both include 'normal' attributes in their codes.

maybe you use different module with the same name. Or maybe you created own class TwoCaptcha and it doesn't have this function. You can use print( dir(solver) ) to see what variables and functions it has. You may also try print( TwoCaptcha.__file__ ) to see in which file you have this class

I installed this module on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu) and when I use print(TwoCaptcha.normal) then it shows something like <function TwoCaptcha.normal at 0x76817c1d93f0>. TwoCaptcha.__file__ doesn't exists but TwoCaptcha.__module__ gives 'twocaptcha.solver'

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

So... Found the problem and shearing the solution for people like me:
Apparently, I've been using a deprecated version of 2capltcha's dependency (called 'TwoCaptcha').
The active one is called '2captcha-python'.
The deprecated one just didn't have the needed functionality

Good afternoon, try running the code using the python3 command.
Example:
python3 main.py
Or use a virtual environment.
